# Can I redirect to a CDN only when the origin server is under load?

Tags: redirect, cdn

I want to host web content that could become viral, but I'm cost sensitive.  I want the protection of a CDN, but don't want to pay for it unless its needed.

I *think* CDN usage typically routes all requests through the CDN, but this isn't my expertise.  I'd prefer an architecture where the origin server handles most requests, but the CDN takes over under load.  Are there any CDNs which support something like this natively?

I'd happily have the origin server HTTP-redirect to CDN, if under load.  This is such a simple solution I feel like it must be wrong.  Is this a terrible idea?

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend redirecting to a CDN. That has a couple of problems:

1. Redirects cause URL changes. Changing the URL temporarily is bad for usability and SEO.
2. Your server would still get hit for each request to issue the redirect. Issuing redirects is less intensive that serving content, but if something goes viral it could still bring down your server.

It might be possible to adjust your DNS records to point to a CDN only when your server comes under load.  To make that work you would have to set up the CDN ahead of time and just not use it.  CDNs typically want to become your DNS host, so you would change your NS records to use the CDNs DNS servers and then make configuration changes in the CDN when your server comes under load. Some CDNs even have programmatic APIs to support cases like this.  Switching over to a CDN using DNS would take at minimum half an hour.  You would have to set your DNS TTL to as low as possible (30 minutes) ahead of time.

You should also consider that many CDNs have a free tier of service.

- CloudFlare is famous for having free CDN services that work really well.  See their [pricing page](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans/#overview). They have said that they plan to keep their free tier of service indefinitely because developers use it for their personal sites and gain familiarity with their services.  Those users then are more likely to recommend CloudFlare for their employer's enterprise sites that don't fit under the free tier.
- If you are running on AWS, Amazon's CloudFront CDN has a free tier and then makes you pay only when you exceed that usage.